# Best way style on mouseover/mouseout Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I'm dealing with the following issue:

[image: GIF]

As you can see,  all of my elements are taking the mouseover instead of just one. There's a way with arrays on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56199957/event-triggered-on-all-elements-generated-by-ngfor-in-angular-7) thread but I don't know if it's the better suit for me.

Here's my component code.
I'm using an `*ngFor` to generate all of the necessary elements and with the event (`mouseover`) and (`mouseend`) change the style of the image to `css display: none` and `css display: block`.

### component.html

```html
<div class="container-dratini">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let auto of autos">
    <div
      [id]="auto.submarca"
      class="card-cuadro"
      (mouseover)="onMouseOver()"
      (mouseout)="onMouseOut()"
      #cardCuadro
    >
      <header>{{ auto.submarca }} - {{ auto.marca }}</header>
      <div class="text-info" [style.display]="displayText">
        Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
        fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae,
        ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam
        egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend
        leo.
      </div>
      <img
        class="item item-img"
        src="/assets/images/autos/{{ auto.submarca }}.png"
        alt=""
        #img
        (error)="setImageOnError(img)"
        [style.display]="displayImage"
      />
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

### component.ts

```js
export class CuadrosComponent implements OnInit {
  autos: any;
  constructor() {}
  displayText: string;
  displayImage: string;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.autos = AUTOS;
    this.displayImage = "block";
    this.displayText = "none";
  }

  onMouseOver() {
    this.displayText = "block";
    this.displayImage = "none";
  }

  onMouseOut(auto, cardCuadroTag) {
    this.displayText = "none";
    this.displayImage = "block";
  }

  setImageOnError(img) {
    img.src = "/assets/images/autos/not-found.png";
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use CSS for this?

Answer (score 1):

You have a single component that display multiple element you want to style individually. But in order to do so, you are using a single instance variable shared between all those children elements.

The most intuitive solution would be to create a component that would display a single box and handle the mouse events.

Another solution would be to use a dictionnary to know which element should be styled differently, something like:

```
export class CuadrosComponent implements OnInit {
  hoveredComponents: {[id: string]: boolean};
  //...
  onMouseOver(id: string) {
    this.hoveredComponents[id]=true;
  }

  onMouseOut(id: string) {
    this.hoveredComponents[id]=false;
  }
```

html:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let auto of autos">
    <div
      [id]="auto.submarca"
      class="card-cuadro"
      [class.hovered]="hoveredComponents[auto.submarca]"
      (mouseover)="onMouseOver(auto.submarca)"
      (mouseout)="onMouseOut(auto.submarca)"
      #cardCuadro
    >
```

css:

```
.card-cuadro.hovered img {
    display: block;
}
.card-cuadro:not(.hovered) img {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: This is way too complicated solution for something that can be simply achieved via CSS `:hover`.

Answer (score 0):

I already make a solution.
Getting the reference for my html element and acceding his children array where is the image to hide and the text to show and then just changing the style to display: block and vice versa.
Im noob lol.

```js
  onMouseOver(cardCuadroTag) {
    cardCuadroTag.children["2"].style.display = "none";
    cardCuadroTag.children["1"].style.display = "block";
  }

  onMouseOut(cardCuadroTag) {
    cardCuadroTag.children["2"].style.display = "block";
    cardCuadroTag.children["1"].style.display = "none";
  }
```